# Azure AD Auth allow login without domain in username

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a web app that is using an Azure AD to hold user accounts and allow authentication. The app has some internal users that are able to authenticate, but I also want to allow external users into the app (customers external to the company).

I am able to do this, but only by creating users that have "@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" in the username. That is fine I guess.. but can I at configure the sign-on page somehow to not require the username to type this in??

Ex: if a username is "joe.bob@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" I want them to be able to login with a username of "joe.bob" and that's it!

Full disclosure there is another question like this: [Logging into Azure Active Directory without a Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880703/logging-into-azure-active-directory-without-a-domain-name) and I've posted a comment asking if anything has change since the question was active (2014). So if this is a duplicate question, then so be it, but I am wanting to know if there are any new developments (pun intended) regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, you want to collaborate to work with external users. However you were create a account in the tenant directly. There are some difference between the Azure AD user and external user, more detail refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users-external).

And AFAIK, Azure Active Directory still doesn't support to login with the username without domain name at present.

However the Azure AD B2C also provides the feature to work with external users and it allows **Local Accounts** login-in with (email address and password, or username and password).(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview)). You may consider to use Azure AD B2C if you want to login without the domain name.

And below link also helpful about to learn the difference between B2B collaboration and B2C:

[Compare B2B collaboration and B2C in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-compare-b2c)

In-addition, if you have any idea or feedback about Azure AD, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).

Comment: It didn't occur to me until yesterday that there are two separate things: B2C and B2B. Awhile back when I was researching I saw that there was something in Azure we could use, but at a price. Then yesterday I saw some information showing how to (seemingly) achieve what I want using (what I thought) was the same thing I had previously researched.  It must not be. :)  What I saw yesterday was just creating a "New Guest User" that would allow something like a @gmail.com account. They would then receive and invite. I tested and so far it seems OK, but need to test more. Your link will help me too.

Comment: @JzInqXc9Dg If you still have the problem about this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Oh it's still as confusing as it could possibly be to me. :) I just saw in azure something yet even more distinct called "B2C" but it was like a whole different thing in azure that I would need to activate and pay for. How is that different than adding B2C ("guest"?) users in my existing azure ad?

Comment: my big problem now with B2C/AAD is...apparently azure doesn't return B2C users' group claim like it does for normal users?! for an app I'm almost done with. Amazing to find this out at the last minute. Is there really no way to get a B2C/guest user's group claims from AAD??? I understand I can via the Graph API, but I have front end code that utilities the claims object being returned from AAD. And it is missing the group claims for B2C users. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b

Comment: Azure B2C tenant doesn't support issue the Group claims in the token. As a workaround, the front code can call a back-end to get the group membership. And if you also require this feature, please vote up the feedback you post. And there is no way to add B2C users in existing Azure AD, we need to create a Azure B2C tenant. It is different with normal Azure AD. You can refer [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/?v=17.23h) about the Azure B2C tenant.

Comment: I am talking about "guest users" in the normal azure AD then. They also don't seem to issue the group claims in the token - and I think I've seen people around the internet throwing around the term B2C when talking about these types of accounts. Probably because they achieve what B2C seems to achieve (for me anyway): adding external users to the group and not requiring them to have the same domain as my directory. What is the difference between guest users and B2C users?

Comment: sorry - i made a mistake. my external user in my normal AAD does indeed include a groups claim. I should be able to make use of this just fine (otherwise I would just call the graph API like you mentioned to get that information. which I may still do in some instances)

Comment: B2C is a tenant which is different with normal tenant. And it support to login using the work or school accounts, local accounts and social accounts. The guest users(external users) only able to login-in using the Microsoft Account or work or school accounts. And you can check the limitation of external users from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users-external#external-user-management-and-limitations). Hope it is helpful.